# I get 'R Session Aborted' when installing any package in RStudio

Tags: r, installation, package, rstudio, lubridate

When I try to install a package, I get the following message on RStudio

```r
install.packages("lubridate")
```

R Session Aborted

[image]

EDIT : It does work in RGui though

```r
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---   
trying URL 'https://cran.irsn.fr/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/lubridate_1.8.0.zip'  
Content type 'application/zip' length 1719785 bytes (1.6 MB) downloaded 1.6 MB    
package ‘lubridate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked  
The downloaded binary packages are in   
        C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUF39l4\downloaded_packages
```

But when I load the package in RStudio, I get  an error

```
library(lubridate)

Error in library(lubridate) : there is no package called ‘lubridate`
```

Comment: What happens if you open R itself (not within RStudio) and run that line?

Comment: It does work in RGui !

Comment: That's interesting. I would just check that you have the latest version of RStudio, and that the installation is succesful by running `library(lubridate)`. If both are true, it might be worth filing an issue to RStudio about it.

Comment: But when I load the package in RStudio with `library(lubridate)`, I get `Error in library(lubridate) : there is no package called ‘lubridate`

Comment: Ok, so the installation was not successful. Can you copy and paste the the output of `install.packages("lubridate")`?

Comment: The ouput in RGui ?

Comment: `--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cran.irsn.fr/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/lubridate_1.8.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1719785 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

package ‘lubridate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUF39l4\downloaded_packages`

Comment: I'm not sure why the package is not being seen by R after its installation. If you run `.libPaths()` and go that folder, do you have your other packages installed fine?

Comment: Run `.libPaths()` in both RGui and RStudio. I suspect they are different, and maybe RStudio is trying to use a library in a location it doesn't have permission for or something. Reinstalling RStudio might be a good step too.

Comment: I had launched RGui but not with the same version of R as the one running in RStudio. I ran `install.packages("lubridate")` with the correct RGui (R 4.2.1) and now lubridate can be loaded in RStudio